# Change note dates in Evernote

Tags: evernote

I have just started using Evernote this morning, and it looks like a really great replacement for OneNote now my license is expired.

I have a dream journal that I would like to transfer to Evernote, but I would like to be able to create notes in Evernote for a particular date, where there is no obvious means of doing this.  Is this feasible and how can I do it?

Answer (score 3):

If you are referring to the "Created" date, it is usually automatically assigned when you first enter the note, and when you edit the file the last update is also shown. (Full history is also available to Premium users.)  Each of these dates however can be edited by clicking on the down arrow in the upper right corner (next to the www icon).  This will open up the header data for editing.